# Problems installing ng-cordova. Cordova-plugin-geolocation.PositionError not found?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm not really used to installing plugins but I followed the guide on the website to the letter in installing ng-cordova on an ionic app.

1º downloaded the lib

2º Added it to the index, before cordova.js and after angular

3º added the modules dependency

4º installed the plugin itself on the plugins folder

But I keep getting this error, regartheless of what I do, trying to launch the mobile app on cordovaSim. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? A step I missed? Is it because I'm using CordovaSim? It's just a lot trickier to do debugging on the cellphone.

```
!JavaScript ERROR: module cordova-plugin-geolocation.PositionError not found on line 71 for http://localhost:6732/cordova.js 
!JavaScript LOG: deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
!JavaScript LOG: Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem , did you solve it ?

Comment: Same in here. Any chance?